# What is the default action when I don't set http_cache in view config in Pyramid framework

Tags: pyramid, browser-cache, cache-control

Regarding the document of [Pyramid framework](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/docs/pyramid/en/latest/narr/viewconfig.html), they description how to user http_cache parameter.

However, this document doesn't explain the default action if user doesn't set this parameter.
The default action mean browser will cache the response or not cache the response or base on the behavior for each browser

So, could you please share this case to me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First, if your web server supports it, you can configure your web server to set Expires and Cache-Control response headers. Your web server's documentation should explain how it interacts with CGI scripts and web frameworks that also may set these headers.

Second, when you set the http_cache argument in Pyramid, then you can set Expires and Cache-Control response headers depending on the values in the argument. If you omit this argument, then Pyramid does nothing in this regard.

Finally web browsers may have their own caching mechanism.

This article, [Caching Tutorial for Web Authors and Webmasters](https://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/), is an excellent and thorough discussion on the matter.